# Change inner text inside legend tag manually

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make text inside legend tag manually editable for user like it's possible to do with text or label elements ?

```
<legend > Blablabla</legend>
<input type="text" value="Blablabla " ></input>
```

And by clicking on text or label element i can type whatever i want and this will change that text, but with legend it's not possible like if legend tag would have "disabled" property. **I know that this is innerHTML vs. value of input, but is it possible  somehow to allow to do that ??Like simple, manual change in browser(no scripts to do that) ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a solution which actually [works in most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable#Compatibility)

Add `contenteditable="true"` to your legend like this:

```
<legend contenteditable="true"> Blablabla</legend>
```

But this will not update the `input` element. If you want to do that just forgo the `legend` element and use a regular text `input`.